# Retrieving the entities namespace from the EntityManager

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to retrieve the namespace of my `Doctrine` entities from an instance of `EntityManager`.

I can set the namespace as follows:

```
$em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
$sm = $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager();
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver($sm);
$driver->setNamespace('My\Entities');
$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
```

However I can't retrieve it:

```
$em->getConfiguration()->getMetadataDriverImpl()->getNamespace();
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver::getNamespace()

If I search `Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DatabaseDriver.php` I can see `setNamespace()` but not `getNamespace()`, and the `namespace` property is private :(

**How can I retrieve the namespace of my Doctrine entities from an instance of EntityManager?**

Answer (score 0):

```
$em->getConfiguration()->getEntityNamespaces();
```

Comment: Care to add some comments? Maybe is the correct answer, but adding some comments will help the OP and anyone else to better understand your answer.

Comment: hmm, the method is there, but I'm getting a `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: entityNamespaces in Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php on line 199` message. There is a `getEntityNamespace($namespaceAlias)` method but it requires an alias and fails if I don't provide it...